# Using mergeCells() in openxlsx package R creates error in output

Tags: r, dataframe, openxlsx

I'm trying to output a data frame in R into excel but I keep getting an error when I use mergeCells() when trying to open the resulting xlsx file. While the cells do merge, my data is "lost." I can unmerge the cells and the data is there but I want to format it so the output (ex. column 1 of my df) spans over multiple columns.

I've tried merging the cells before and after writing the data to the worksheet. I've also tried using writeDataTable() and writeData(), both did not work. I've tried starting the df on different columns (as seen below). For example, start writing the df to column 2, and merge columns 1:2. The other one I merged columns 1:2 first then wrote data starting on column 1.

```
df <- data.frame(
Category = c("A", "B", "C"),
Type = c("x", "y", "z"),
Number = c("1", "2", "3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

book <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- "Sheet1"
writeData(book, sheet, df, startCol = 2, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)
mergeCells(book, sheet, cols = 1:2, rows = 1)
mergeCells(book, sheet, cols = 1:2, rows = 2)
mergeCells(book, sheet, cols = 1:2, rows = 3)
saveWorkbook(book)
```

OR

```
mergeCells(book, sheet, cols = 1:2, rows = 1)
mergeCells(book, sheet, cols = 1:2, rows = 2)
mergeCells(book, sheet, cols = 1:2, rows = 3)    
writeDataTable(book, sheet, df, startCol = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(book)
```

When opening the file after saving, the error is "We found a problem with some content, etc.  Excel was able to open the file by removing or repairing unreadable content."

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you want as the final answer. You are writing 3 columns. You want the format of column 1 to be applied to column 1 and column 2. You want to see the content of column 1, column 2 and column 3. Is that correct?

Comment: @awchisholm I want column 1 to have merged cells while column 2 and 3 are in unmerged cells. So the excel output has column 1 merged into cells A:B and column 2 in cell C and column 3 in cell D. I hope that explained it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to merge columns 1 and 2 to produce a merged column with the first column of `df`. If this is correct, then your issue is that the left most column to which you are merging (column 1) is blank. `openxlsx::mergeCells()` will then keep the content of the left-most column merged. To merge columns 1 and 2 and have the contents of `df[1]` in it, you need to write the content of `df[1]` on the left-most column like so:

```
library(openxlsx)

df <- data.frame(
  Category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Type = c("x", "y", "z"),
  Number = c("1", "2", "3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

wb <- createWorkbook() # creates workbook
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1") # adds sheet
writeData(wb, 1, df[1], startCol = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE) # writing content on the left-most column to be merged
writeData(wb, 1, df[2:3], startCol = 3, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE) # write the rest of the content on the columns that wont be merged
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df) + 1)){ # loop over rows for merging
  mergeCells(wb, 1, cols = 1:2, rows = i)
}
rm(i)
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = T) # save workbook
```

Comment: @Sgarg you're welcome! You're really close to get it right Cheers

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had a similar problem to merge a region with multiple rows. For future readers of this thread, I would add that, more generally, `mergeCells` keeps the content of the *top-left* cell.